# Connecting Sequelize to Postgres installed with Homebrew

Tags: javascript, postgresql, node.js

I'm trying to use [Sequelize](https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize) to connect to my local install of Postgres. I installed it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and have confirmed that I can connect and query the database just fine. When I run Sequelize it outputs valid queries (I ran them via console) but the database doesn't change and doesn't log any connection. My current code is:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('reliable_rabbit', 'mohammad', null, {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  dialect: 'postgres',
  define: { timestamps: true, paranoid: true, underscore: true }//,
});
```

I can connect to the database via: `psql -d reliable_rabbit -U mohammad -h 127.0.0.1`. I am using version `1.5.0-beta` of Sequelize.

Edit:

In my entry point (app/app.js), logs nothing:

```
var models = require('./models');
models.Post.sync().success(function(){
  console.log("Success!")
}).error(function(error){
  console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

app/models.js:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize")

var sequelize = new Sequelize('reliable_rabbit', 'mohammad', null, {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  logging: console.log,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  define: { timestamps: true, paranoid: true, underscore: true }//,
});
exports.Post = require("../models/post")(sequelize);
```

and finally models/post.js:

var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

```
module.exports = function(sequelize) {
  return sequelize.define('post', {
    title: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { notEmpty: true } },
    permalink: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { is: ["^[a-z]+[a-z\-][a-z]+$"] } },
    content: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, validate: { notEmpty: true } },
    published: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
    published_at: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
  },{
    instanceMethods: {
      generatePermalink: function() {
        this.permalink = this.title.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g,'').replace(/\-{2,}/g, '-');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: From what you say, I assume that postgresql is running on the default port and that u don't need a password, right? Can u maybe provide some more code?

Comment: Correct. I'll edit in the model and how I have it setup where it logs the query, but doesn't seem to execute it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

first of all i would recommend the use of [sequelize.import](http://sequelizejs.com/#models-import). furthermore i'm wondering if you probably just forgot to [sync](http://sequelizejs.com/#models-sync) the database? Please let me know if you need further details about those things :)